# How to restrict Nexus OSS to specific PyPI package?

Tags: python, proxy, nexus, pypi

I have one group-repository (local + proxy to pypi . org).
Also I have my own package with name N, which is also listed ony PyPI with name N (but it's completely different). How to make trick that Nexus blocks all browse and read access to PyPI server ONLY for this specific package (with name N)?

Comment: Could you just move the local repository to first in the group order?  Then it should find yours before even searching proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately, it finds all packages in all repositories. I tried this trick, but no

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?